# Accepting Int or String in graphQL schema

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I have an input type in my apollo graphql schema, My schema looks like:

```
input Score {
    total: String! // The input we recieve from the user might be a string or an int.
    
  }
```

So, I want the total to be an string or int. How can I implement that? Should I use custom scalar types or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your Schema can be as it are!

```
typeDefs= gql`
input Score{
   total: String!
}

type mutation{
   totalBE: (input: Score)
}
`
```

```
Query:{
    totalBe: ScoreBe(_,param);

}
```

but in the back end function resoolver

```
resoolvers = {
ScoreBe(paramArgs):{
   score = paramArgs.input.total;
      //deal with it as String and Interger at the same time in your middleware or backEnd Technollogy. (is most easy here).

}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).